# Material Design Lite - animation not work inside ng-view div

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design-lite

Do you know why the first button animation does not working, after refresh the page? After click the first button we can only see the button shadow but animation not working. Thank u in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
</div>
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-color--accent">
    <i class="material-icons mdl-color-text--white" role="presentation">add</i>
</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.2/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-color--accent">
<i class="material-icons mdl-color-text--white" role="presentation">add</i>
```

```
var shaApp = angular.module('shaApp', ['ngAnimate','ngRoute']);
shaApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
   }
]);
shaApp.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {}}]);
```

Answer (score 8):

You might need to upgrade the dynamic elements (as referenced [here](http://www.getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic)).

```
shaApp.run(function($rootScope, $location, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
        });
    });
});
```

*[edit] fix misspelled word

Comment: Using routes, when a view are loaded the components registered using componentHandler does not working.
This code solve my problem with AngularJS, Material Design Lite and Routes. Thanks!

Comment: Great!! Thanks Fumler

Comment: Thank you loads! this saved the day.